# Can I use "%s" recursively?

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace

Can I use `%s` recursively in Python 2.7? I tried (Python novice alert!)

```
spss.Submit('SAVE OUTFILE = "%s".')%os.path.join(wdir,"PrepareTableScript_%s.sav"%str(ver).zfill(2))
```

so in the string that replaces the `%s`, there's another `%s`. The error I get is:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'`

but the local variables `ver` and `wdir` do print out correctly. Do I get this error because I'm trying to use `%s` recursively or is something else wrong with this (attempted) code?

Comment: Short answer: Yes!, but the better question is, why didn't you just try it yourself? Break down the problem, and I am sure you could figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using *anything* recursively here, you are merely nesting expressions (which is fine).

Your problem is that you left the *first* `%` operator outside of the `Submit()` call. You are applying it not to a string, but to a return value here, and `Submit()` returns `None`. Move it inside the parenthesis:

```
spss.Submit('SAVE OUTFILE = "%s".' % 
    os.path.join(wdir, "PrepareTableScript_%s.sav" % str(ver).zfill(2))
)
```

Comment: Huge thanks! The code works now and I also understand what was wrong and why this error popped up!

Answer (score 3):

You have this:

```
spss.Submit('SAVE OUTFILE = "%s".') % os.path.join(...)
```

It should be this:

```
spss.Submit('SAVE OUTFILE = "%s".' % os.path.join(...))
```